# Getting new position of a line after rotation

Tags: wpf, rotation, line, coordinates, transform

I need to find out new coordinates of line after rotation using RotateTransform method on a line.
For example, after this line:

```
line.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(25, 0, 0);
```

`line.X1` and the three other properties don't change. I have found some solution for shapes like rectangular, but it doesn't work for line. Line has different way how to treat with it.

*EDIT:* Thanks for your help **H.B.** The second way is exactly what I've been looking for.

**SOLUTION:**

```
Line line = new Line();
line.X1 = 10;
line.Y1 = 10;
line.X2 = 20;
line.Y2 = 30;

RotateTransform rotation = new RotateTransform();
Point p1 = rotation.Transform(new Point(line.X1, line.Y1));
Point p2 = rotation.Transform(new Point(line.X2, line.Y2));

line.X1 = p1.X;
line.Y1 = p1.Y;
line.X2 = p2.X;
line.Y2 = p2.Y;
```

This code rotates the line and sets a new values of coordinates to attached properties of this line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.generaltransform.transform.aspx) points on their own:

```
var transform = new RotateTransform(25, 0, 0);
var newP1 = transform.Transform(new Point(line.X1,line.Y1));
//...
```

If you want a permanent transformation you can transform the start and end points and assign the new values to the respective properties.